# How to set the current host for Passport strategy callbackURL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using the Passport-Linkedin strategy for Passport with Express, to allow users to log in with their LinkedIn profile.

I have the following code:

```
passport.use(new LinkedInStrategy({
    consumerKey: config.linkedin.LINKEDIN_API_KEY,
    consumerSecret: config.linkedin.LINKEDIN_SECRET_KEY,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/linkedin/callback"
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    // asynchronous verification, for effect...
    process.nextTick(function () {

      // To keep the example simple, the user's LinkedIn profile is returned to
      // represent the logged-in user.  In a typical application, you would want
      // to associate the LinkedIn account with a user record in your database,
      // and return that user instead.
      return done(null, profile);
    });
  }
));
```

On line 4, I have to set the full callback URL manually. I had one string for production and one for development, but my URLs keep changing, and so do the ports (I use 2 machines to develop).

How can I set the first portion of the URL (`http://localhost:3000`) automatically? Is there a property of `express` or `app` that would allow me to do that? Do I need to resort to an `app.use(function(req, res){});`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Old question, possibly answer only valid for newer versions. However if someone runs into this, like me, solution is just to not specify a hostname in the `callbackURL`:

```
passport.use(new LinkedInStrategy({
    consumerKey: config.linkedin.LINKEDIN_API_KEY,
    consumerSecret: config.linkedin.LINKEDIN_SECRET_KEY,
    callbackURL: "/auth/linkedin/callback"
  },
```

To get this to work for heroku https redirect, we have to tell the system to trust the `x-forwarded-protocol` headers, by trusting the proxy:

```
passport.use(new LinkedInStrategy({
    consumerKey: config.linkedin.LINKEDIN_API_KEY,
    consumerSecret: config.linkedin.LINKEDIN_SECRET_KEY,
    callbackURL: "/auth/linkedin/callback",
    proxy: true
  },
```

Comment: It doesn't work if your app is not running on root path, for example it is running on `/myapp` instead of `/`.

Answer (score 0):

In my config.js I have a cfg.site_url, that's one way, or you could look at req.host

http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.host

```
// Host: "example.com:3000"
req.hostname
// => "example.com"
```

Not sure if you have a req object in your context there.

Comment: I started with a config string, but server names and ports keep changing. I'm on the app level - the only way to get a req, as far as I know, is to add that app.use statement I mentioned. The problem is, it then gets called for every request.

Comment: you can provide a middleware for your one request. Something like `app.get('/whatever', loadConfigVariable, routes.whatever);` and `app.locals.whatever = config.whatever` inside loadConfigVariable function.

Comment: That's what I was trying to avoid - another route. I wonder if I can just find that functionality in Passport itself?

Comment: i'm not a passport guy, so maybe there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually solved this by dynamically building the callback URL from pieces of URL and the actual port. Not happy with this solution as it looks non-elegant, but could not find a way to get the actual URL without adding a middleware use call (which I'm sure impacts performance more than a simple string concatenation).